# Class reference from Generic parameter class

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2009

I have a persistence framework, and I am trying to use generics so I don't have to keep creating new list classes for each type of object I want to store in a type safe way.

I have a method that returns the class of the contained object in the list class (so I know which queries to run and which object to create.

As an example, it looks something like this:

```
type

  TMyObject = class

  end;
  TMyObjectClass = class of TMyObject;


  TMyObjectList = class
  public
    function ListClass: TMyObjectClass; virtual; abstract;

  end;

  TMyObjectList<T: TMyObject, constructor> = class(TMyObjectList)
  public
    function ListClass: TMyObjectClass; override;

  end;

implementation

{ TMyObjectList<T> }

function TMyObjectList<T>.ListClass: TMyObjectClass;
begin
  result := T;  //  <==== this wont compile
end;

end.
```

Is there a way of returning the class of the generic parameter in this case?

Thanks

N@
(using Delphi 2009)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [a known issue in Delphi 2009.](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=67762)  It's been fixed in 2010.  I just tested it and your code compiles just fine there.

Comment: You. Are. A. Legend. Thanks! Can't wait to get 2010 (should be tomorrow, yay!).

Comment: Cool!  The enhanced RTTI will make persistence a lot easier, BTW. :)

Answer (score 0):

T is not an instance of an object.

In your specific example, you should write something like:

result := self;

I think you're looking the wrong way...

Comment: I would like to return a reference to the *class* not a reference to an instantiated object.

Comment: No, `T` is not an instance of an object. `T` is a class. You're confused because the **constraint** "`T: TMyObject`" looks like a variable declaration where `T` would be a `TMyObject` reference. Generics mean that classes now how *type parameters* in the same way that functions have *value parameters*.